React + TypeScript: Vite Build Error with "import.meta" Properties
I’m working on a React and TypeScript project using Vite for bundling. The issue arises during the build process. I’ve installed all dependencies correctly, and the dev server runs fine, but the build fails with errors related to import.meta.
Error:
Here’s the error message I’m getting:
X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"

  (define name):1:0:
    1 │ import.meta.dirname
      ╵ ~~~~~~

X [ERROR] Expected identifier but found "import"

  (define name):1:0:
    1 │ import.meta.filename
      ╵ ~~~~~~

failed to load config from path/to/vite.config.ts
error during build:
Error: Build failed with 3 errors:
...




To resolve this issue, try downgrading esbuild to version 0.24.0 by running the following command:
npm install -D esbuild@0.24.0

This should fix the build errors related to import.meta.
